# Clickable images in a canvas

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the images inside a canvas clickable, but I am confused on how to go about that, here is what I have currently, I just want pictures[0] to be clickable and that alert to occur once it is clicked, but for some reason it is not working. How can i make it so that when picture[0] is clicked the alert goes off.

```
 var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
 var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
 var left = c.offsetLeft;
 var top = c.offsetTop;
 var pictures = [];
  //wheel
 pictures[0] = new Image();
 pictures[0].src = 'images/Layer8.png';
//bg
 pictures[1] = new Image();
pictures[1].src = 'images/Layer0.png';
//gear
 pictures[2] = new Image();
pictures[2].src = 'images/Layer7.png';
 //speed
 pictures[3] = new Image();
pictures[3].src = 'images/Layer14.png';
//dial1
pictures[4] = new Image();
pictures[4].src = 'images/Layer18.png';
//dial2
 pictures[5] = new Image();
pictures[5].src = 'images/Layer16.png';
//dial3
 pictures[6] = new Image();
 pictures[6].src = 'images/Layer17.png';

 c.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    var x = event.pageX - left,
    y = event.pageY - top;
    pictures.forEach(function(fx,fy,fwidth,fheight,x,y) {
    if (y > fy && y < fy + fheight 
        && x > fx && x < fx + fwidth) {
        alert('clicked an element');
    }
});
}, false);

function load(){
ctx.drawImage(pictures[1],0,0);
ctx.drawImage(pictures[2],468,263);
ctx.drawImage(pictures[3],89,77);
ctx.drawImage(pictures[4],146,153);
ctx.drawImage(pictures[5],278,153);
ctx.drawImage(pictures[6],206,119);
ctx.drawImage(pictures[0],fx,fy,fwidth,fheight);

}
var fx = 84;
var fy = 60;
var fwidth = 283;
var fheight = 276;
```

window.onload = load;

Comment: what is happening right now?

Comment: nothing. when I click nothing occurs. I am not used to having images on a canvas be clicked.

Comment: Hey Connor Morrison did my answer help you out?

Comment: Hey Connor if my answer helped you out I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I understand what you are trying to do.  Unfortunately, images in the canvas are not DOM elements, only the canvas itself is one. This means using jQuery you can call:

```
$('#myCanvas').on('click', function() {});
```

or natively:

```
c.addEventListener('click', function(){});
```

However, the [fabricjs.com](http://fabricjs.com/) library may prove to be useful to you in this case.